# how to swap an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to do a show/hide function, but I having a problem in swapping the image(bootstrap class).
The show-hide function is working, the problem is that I don't know how to detect which class is in display....with the code that I have I am able to change  the class from min to plus....then the user click again the button, it display the content but it remains the plus class.

HTMl.

```
<span class="glyphicon show-hide glyphicon-minus"></span>
```

JS.

```
$('.glyphicon-minus').click(function()
{
    $('.show-hide').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    $(this).closest('div').next('.widget-content').slideToggle();

    var $classto = $('.glyphicon-plus');
    $classto.is(':visible')
    {
        $('.show-hide').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the glyphicon-plus class remained mainly is because you targetted ".glyphicon-minus" class in your event listener. But when you change your class glyphicon-minus does not exist. Switching that you to a class that remains on the element should do the trick.

I also refactored your code a bit.

```
$('.show-hide').on("click",function()
{       
    if ($(this).hasClass("glyphicon-minus")){
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    }else{
      $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    }
    $(this).closest('div').next('.widget-content').slideToggle();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.show-hide').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.hasClass('glyphicon-minus')) {
    $this
      .removeClass('glyphicon-minus')
      .addClass('glyphicon-plus')
      .closest('div')
      .next('.widget-content')
      .slideUp();
  }
  else {
    $this
      .removeClass('glyphicon-plus')
      .addClass('glyphicon-minus')
      .closest('div')
      .next('.widget-content')
      .slideDown();
  }
});
```

Or, assuming your html is correctly initialized:

```
$('.show-hide').on('click', function(){
    $(this)
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus')
      .closest('div')
      .next('.widget-content')
      .slideToggle();
});
```

(Generally, you don't want to mix toggle functions with non-toggle functions.)

Comment: no need for a .slideUp and a .slideDown function call, slideToggle does both

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou `.slideToggle()` also gets confused in certain situations.

Comment: @Ouroborus it's only confusing if you don't have any idea of what your code is doing. Otherwise, slidetoggle simplies things as you're wanting a `toggling` effect.

Comment: @A.Lau I draw that bit of knowledge from experience. It's entirely possible, when mixing jQuery's toggle functions with their non-toggle counterparts, to end up in a situation where, after things start off fine, a few accidental clicks and drags end up with the toggle reversed from how you wanted it.

Comment: Hmm i would need to test that but maybe you are right

Comment: in what situation would you want to use both toggle and non-toggle functions together?

Comment: @A.Lau You wouldn't. But here we are with OP (and the accepted answer) doing exactly that.

Comment: @Ouroborus I don't see them using anything but `slideToggle`? Sorry, if I'm interpretting something incorrectly

Comment: @A.Lau They're using `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()` alongside `.slideToggle()`.

Comment: True enough, they could simplify it with just toggling the class too, but I think the code is clear enough that you shouldn't get confused as to what's going on, since the classnames are pretty obvious in and of themselves. Not to say that your code is confusing in comparison, but I'm just against the opinion that using `toggle` with other non-toggling functions suddenly makes the code confusing.

Comment: @A.Lau I was anthropomorphizing the code. There are (were? It's been a while) situations where a toggle combined with a non-toggle could end up where the intended state of the toggle is reversed in respect to the non-toggle. This only happened under unusual user activity.